# Derived Subgroup and Factor Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N \unlhd G$, does it holds that $(G/N)' = G'N /N$, or more generally for any subgroup $H \le G$ we have $(HN/N)' = H'N/N$? Does anyone has a proof of this fact?

PS: Side-Question: Is it wrong to write $(G/N)' = G'/N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $x=hn$ and $y=km$ with $h,k\in H,\ n,m\in N$, and use equations like $nk=k(k^{-1}nk)\in HN$ to pull each $h,k,h^{-1},k^{-1}$ in front of all $N$-elements. Thus you will see that $[x,y]\in H'N$. 
(So, it means $(HN)'\subseteq H'N$.)

Conversely,  if $g\in H'$ then $g$ is a product of commutators $[h_i,k_i]$, then any  $sN\in H'N/N$ can be written as $s=gn$ for some $g\in H'$ and $n\in N$, but then $sN=gnN=gN=[h_1N,k_1N][h_2N,k_2N]\dots\ \in (HN/N)'$.

Comment: i) by normality of $N$ we have $$[x,y] = hnkmn^{-1} h^{-1} m^{-1} k^{-1} = hk(k^{-1}nk) n'' h^{-1} m^{-1} k^{-1} = hkn' n'' h^{-1} m^{-1} k^{-1} = hk n''' h^{-1} m^{-1} k^{-1} = hkh^{-1} (hn''' h^{-1}) m^{-1} k^{-1} = hkh^{-1} m' m^{-1} k^{-1} = hkh^{-1} m'' k^{-1} = hkh^{-1}k^{-1} (km''k^{-1}) \in H' N.$$ For ii) let me note that $[\cdot, \cdot] : G \to G$ and $[\cdot,\cdot] : G/N \to G/N$ denote two different functions here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is correct, that is $(G/N)'=G'N/N$, but it is wrong to write $(G/N)'=G'/N$, since $N$ does not have to be a subgroup of $G'$.

Proofs can be given by writing out everything mod $N$. Can give it later if you want, but first try it yourself. And $(HN/N)'=H'N/N$ is correct too.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be the canonical homomorphism $G \rightarrow G/N$.
Every element of $(G/N)'$ is of the form $[f(x_1), f(y_1)]\cdots [f(x_n), f(y_n)] = [x_1, y_1]\cdots [x_n, y_n]N$, where $[a, b]$ denotes the commutator of $a,b$.
Hence $(G/N)' = G'N /N$.
A similar argument can be applied for $(HN/N)' = H'N /N$.